# Unexpected Thread Abort Exception using Tasks. Why?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have a console application running in an app domain. The app domain is started by a custom windows service. The application uses parent tasks to start several child tasks that do work. There can be many parent tasks with children running at any given time as the timer looks for new work.

The handle to all parent tasks is in a List of tasks:

```
 static List<Task> _Tasks = new List<Task>();
```

The windows service is able to send a stop signal to the running application by putting a string token in an app domain slot when an admin changes an xml config file (or when the calling service is shut down). The application is running on a timer and checks for a signal to shut down in the slot, then attempts to gracefully conclude what it is doing by waiting for all tasks to end.

Tasks are started like so:

```
Task parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (var invoiceList in exportBucket)
                {
                    KeyValuePair<string, List<InvoiceInfo>> invoices = new KeyValuePair<string, List<InvoiceInfo>>();
                    invoices = invoiceList;
                    string taskName = invoices.Key; //file name of input file
                    Task<bool> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(state => ExportDriver(invoices),
                        taskName, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                }
            });
            _Tasks.Add(parent);
```

A custom GAC dll holds a class that does the work. There are no shared objects in the GAC function. The GAC class is instantiated in each child task:

```
Export export = new Export();
```

Each child task calls a method at some point during execution:

```
foreach (var searchResultList in SearchResults)
{
      foreach (var item in searchResultList)
      {
          if (item.Documents.Count > 0)
          {
              //TODO: this is where we get thread issue if telling service to stop
              var exported = export.Execute(searchResultList);
              totalDocuments += exported.ExportedDocuments.Count();
          }
      }
 }
```

`searchResultList` is not shared between tasks. While the application runs, export.Execute performs as expected for all child tasks. When the stop signal is detected in the application, it attempts to wait for all child tasks to end. I've tried a couple ways to wait for the child tasks under each parent to end:

```
foreach (var task in _Tasks){task.Wait();}
```

and

```
while (_Tasks.Count(t => t.IsCompleted) != _Tasks.Count){}
```

While the wait code executes a threading exception occurs:

```
Error in Export.Execute() method: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thead was being aborted at WFT.CommonExport.Export.Execute(ICollection '1 searchResults)
```

I do not wish to use a cancellation token as I want the tasks to complete, not cancel.

I am unclear why the GAC class method is unhappy since each task should have a unique handle to the method object.

**UPDATE**:

Thanks for the comments. Just to add further clarification to what was going on here...

In theory, there shouldn't be any reason the approach of waiting on child tasks:

```
while (_Tasks.Count(t => t.IsCompleted) != _Tasks.Count){}
```

shouldn't work, though

```
Task.WaitAll()
```

is certainly a better approach, and helped flesh out the problem. After further testing it turns out that one of the issues was that when the app domain application told the calling service no work was being done by populating a slot read by the service:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("Status", "Not Exporting");
```

the timing and placement of that statement in code was wrong in the application. Being new to multithreading, it took me a while to figure out tasks were still running when I issued `SetData` to "Not Exporting". And so, when the service thought it was OK to shut down and tore down the app domain, I believe that caused the `ThreadAbortException`. I've since moved the `SetData` statement to a more reliable location.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `Task.WaitAll(_Tasks)`?

Comment: Good idea. I added Task[] tasks = _Tasks.ToArray();
                Task.WaitAll(tasks); but I get the same error unfortunately when I cancel during the task operations.

Comment: Actually, this did change things somewhat. I have not been able to force the exception when cancelling during task execution any more. But the full work of the tasks never completes. While I've designed for this kind of failure, I have to wonder if the fact that the task method is calling second method has any bearing.

Comment: @Jim On further testing I find that this is working now with the WaitAll(), and that the timing of when I tell the application to shut down is subtle. The design needs to (and does) recover state when the service starts up again. Good tip. Thanks.

Comment: The AttachedToParent option means you don't have to do anything. Just send the Stop signal and proceed to the Exit (in your Parent task). Alternatively, try your current code w/o that option.

Comment: @Henk I kind of get what you are saying and this would work via the xml config change, but (as I've edited the post to clarify), shutting down the service also sends the stop signal and if I were to return to the service too early it would tear down the app domain too soon. I run many app domains under the service so need some orchestration. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question: you are receiving a thread-abort because tasks are executed on a "background" thread.

**Background threads are not waited-on before application terminating**.   See [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0(v=vs.71).aspx)  for further explanation.

Now to try to help solve your actual problem, I would suggest the `Task.WaitAll()` method Jim mentions, however you should handle application termination more robustly. I suspect that while you wait for tasks to complete before shutting down, you don't prevent new tasks from being enqueued.

I would recommend an exit-blocking semaphore and the system that enques tasks increment this on initialization, and decrement on dispose.

Comment: Thanks jaysun. Indeed I did implement something similar and everything seems to be working champion for a manual service stop. In some shutdown scenarios, such as system reboot, and since this is running as a service, there is little you can do however.

Comment: it's harder, but you can still attempt to handle shutdown events gracefully:

1) hook the win32 api's related to system shutdown
2) implement a transaction system.   what I do with one of my apps is to save the work-buffer to the disk, and after successfully completing the work, i delete it from disk.   thus if it gets aborted (or crashes) in the middle of processing I can retry later.   this means there is some small chance of performing the same work twice, but my app handles this situation gracefully.   

anyway, hope that helps :)     good luck on this.