# Exception: Thread was being aborted when not dealing with a Response.End issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web app that has a page that I call every 30 minutes to activate a worker. About 5-7 times a week, I get a `Thread was being aborted` exception

The aspx looks somewhat like that:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script runat="server"> 
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory         
            .StartNew(() => { new MyApplicationWorker().RunApplicationWorker(); });
    }   
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

In the Web.config, I have this line to prevent timeouts and I know the worker completes in much less time than that.

```
<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" executionTimeout="300" />
```

As you can see, the page loads and calls a worker that runs in the background. There's no Response.End issue or Server.Transfer which is what most other posts dealing with this issue revolve around. What can I do prevent the exception from happening?

Comment: what is the IIS pool recycle setting? Maybe the whole app is being recycled?

Comment: Maybe this could be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558145/unexpected-thread-abort-exception-using-tasks-why ? One of the answers quotes MSDN: `Background threads are not waited-on before application terminating`, maybe IIS just recycles the process which kill the thread.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik: The app is hosted (for now) in a shared hosting environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a bug I've been looking to sort out for over a year and all the other related questions seemed to deal with the `Response.End()` problem but here it wasn't the case.

I've always thought that there was something wrong in the methods where the bug occurred but actually it's where the worker gets called that the bug starts.

The solution is simple: I added `.Wait()` and since then the bug's gone from the logs.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory         
      .StartNew(() => { 
          new MyApplicationWorker().RunApplicationWorker().Wait(); 
      });
```

Thanks to alex.b for the comment that lead to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558145/unexpected-thread-abort-exception-using-tasks-why) and I hope this helps others who'll bump into the same issue of worker threads being aborted.